# один XMLHttpRequest внутри другого

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

я новичок в js и хотелось бы узнать как правильно выполнять один XMLHttpRequest внутри другого, т.е. я обращаюсь к интерфейсу api get запросом, получаю от него ответ и на его основе делаю следующий запрос, а на основе ещё одного ответа могу сделать ещё один потом - как это правильно реализовать? я пробую вот так: но у меня не всегда выходит корректно это реализовать

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", 'https://Мой запрос', true);
 xhr.send(null);
 xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (xhr.readyState !== 4) { return; }
   if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var id = data[0]['id'];


       xhr.open("GET", 'https://еще запрос?id='+id, true);
        xhr.send(null);
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) { return; }
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById('aa').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создавайте новый `XMLHttpRequest` (заводя для них разные переменные) для каждого запроса, и все будет хорошо.